# Support of measure vs certain probability

Tags: probability-theory

In the French Wikipedia article https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Radon-Nikodym-Lebesgue, the definition of a being supported by a subset is :

> $\rho$ is said to be supported by $E\in\mathcal A$ (or be concentrated on
> $E$) if for all $A\in\mathcal A$ there is $\rho(A) = \rho(A \cap E)$.

I did a demonstration (which I could write if necessary) that this is equivalent to $\rho(E) = 1$. As it is much simpler than the definition proposed, I suppose my demonstration is flawed. So is my equivalence false, and if this is the case, could you provide a counter-example ?

Comment: I think for ''probability measures'', there is no issue with your definition. It can be proved by setting $A=\mathcal{X}$ where  $\mathcal{X}$ is whole space.

Comment: I think the point of this definition is that a measure is concentrated in a set $E$ if the measure of the complement of $E$ is zero. For probability measures this is equivalent to $E$ having mass one.

Comment: I see, I was so focused on probability measures that I skipped that the Radon-Nikodym-Lebesgue was valid for any measures !